# Break loop when sum of array gets over certain value in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, append, push

I want to break my while loop when the sum of the array that I am appending to gets to a certain number (20). Here's what I've tried:

```
p1_score = []
p2_score = []

until p1_score.inject(:+) >= 20 || p2_score.inject(:+) >= 20 do
```

but I get the following error:

```
`play_game': undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: It's just one of your Int is not set, so you have a nil instead, and you can't do for exemple `1 > nil` 
To help you debug you could use var.class to see what kind is it (Enumerable, Fixnum, Nil ...) and discover which one is nil

Comment: It seems like a bit of a waste to sum both arrays on each iteration rather than just keeping a running total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when `p1_score = []`, `p1_score.inject(:+)` returns `nil`.

A quick fix - and I cannot say for sure whether this is the best solution without seeing more context of your code - would be to explicitly force `inject(:+)` to return an integer, by using the alternate [`Enumerable#inject(initial, sym)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) syntax:

```
until p1_score.inject(0, :+) >= 20 || p2_score.inject(0, :+) >= 20 do
```

Comment: this is perfection personified

Comment: @CarySwoveland care to explain more?

Comment: @hellogoodbye The reason Cary is saying it is ugly is because the interface for inject supports this functionality. You are better off doing something through the interface if it is supported then coming up with your own way to do things.